# Dockerized Jira behind traefik-Proxy throws Mixed-Content-Error

Tags: docker, proxy, jira, reverse-proxy, traefik

I've set up a [Dockerized Jira-Instance](https://cptactionhank.github.io/docker-atlassian-jira-software/) beneath my [Traefik-Installation](https://docs.traefik.io/).

this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  software:
    image: cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:jira.domain.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
```

My Jira-Baseurl is set to https://jira.domain.com and i'm also able to access my Jira-Installation with `https`. In my traefik setup i've setup an redirect from http to https on each request.

my traefik.toml looks like this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
```

This is working, but on some request i get the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jira.domain.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://jira.domain.com/plugins/servlet/gadgets/ifr?container=atlassian&mi…ivitystream-gadget%2Fgadgets%2Factivitystream-gadget.xml&libs=auth-refresh'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I've read that i have to [setup my proxy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html) but am not quiet shure howto do this.